# sort dataframe r by column values

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting

I would like to reorder this dataframe based on the values ​​of the "new" column, how can I do? tell me the exact formula, thanks

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO, Nabboitaliae! Two things, please: (1) Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substituting "DF" as your data frame, you can use this line of code:

```
DF[order(DF$new), ]
```

If you just wanted to view the data frame sorted, you can use

```
View(DF)
```

And click the arrows on the column name, which automatically sorts the data frame by ascending/descending.